# Perl Issue on OS X El Capitan

Tags: osx, perl, non-root-user

For some strange reason, OS X suddenly shows me:

```
Can't locate strict.pm:   Permission denied at /usr/bin/shasum5.18 line 100.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/shasum5.18 line 100.
```

when playing with Homebrew (`brew doctor` for example)

I'm pretty sure it's related to Apple and not Homebrew. As always, I never understood Apple logic at dealing with permissions vs. other *nix!

Before, I could run as a regular user this command:

```
% perl -V
```

Now, I have to run it as a root, which is terribly annoying. Something happened under the hood withough my knowledge.

If I run the command as a regular user, I have:

```
% /usr/bin/perl -V
Can't locate Config.pm:   Permission denied.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

I'd be pleased if anyone could help me run this command as a regular user.

Thanks for your help.

---

Thank you Professors @thrig, Arkadiusz Drabczyk!

This is what I did:

```
% /usr/bin/perl -le 'print for @INC' | while read d; do ls -ld -- "$d"; done
drwxr-xr-x  6 root  wheel  204  1 fév 10:59 /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  wheel  136 17 sep  2015 /Library/Perl/5.18
ls: /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level: No such file or directory
ls: /Network/Library/Perl/5.18: No such file or directory
ls: /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2: Permission denied
drwxr-xr-x  56 root  wheel  1904 25 mai 15:03 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
drwxr-xr-x  130 root  wheel  4420 23 aoû  2015 /System/Library/Perl/5.18
drwxr-xr-x  66 root  wheel  2244 17 sep  2015 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
drwxr-xr-x  109 root  wheel  3706 23 aoû  2015 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
drwx------+ 37 Nathalie  staff  1258  8 jui 22:26 .
```

Good lord! The output `/Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2` was the culprit! I can't believe it!

Fortunately, I managed to compare the related permissions with the ones obtained from my other system with unbroken Perl…

Then, I installed the new permissions:

```
sudo chmod 775 /Library/Perl/Updates
```

I can now `perl -V` as a regular user and start playing.

Comment: It's possible that `Config.pm` is in a directory you cannot read.

Comment: See http://www.keithtwombley.com/pernicious_perl_path_permission_problems/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to an Apple issue, homebrew incorrectly altering `@INC` in such a way that the vendor supplied `/usr/bin/perl` is picking up on those changes, or some user error. `@INC` is a path list where `perl` looks for modules, so

```
% perl -E 'say for @INC'
/Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26
...
```

Ooops that's the MacPorts version I have first in `PATH` so

```
% /usr/bin/perl -E 'say for @INC'
/Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Library/Perl/5.18
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.18
...
```

Those first two paths are from [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) which other setups may or may not have. Regardless, for each of these directories we need to look for permissions problems, as that is the error message. This may be problematical if things are already broken, so you cannot run `perl` to see what `@INC` contains. Okay time to break my system.

```
% chmod 000 /Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5
% perl -E 'say for @INC'
Can't locate feature.pm:   /Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5/feature.pm: Permission denied.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

older forms that do not load modules (such as `feature.pm`) may help, or to run `perl -V`, or to run `perl` on a non-broken installation and then inspect those paths on the broken system. Here we can use an older form of code to get the list of paths:

```
% perl -le 'print for @INC' | while read d; do ls -ld -- "$d"; done
d---------  111 jhqdoe  nsd  3774 Jun  1 10:44 /Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5
...
```

This error is fairly obvious. On other systems you may need to inspect the permissions on each directory in the path, as someone may have misconfigured `/` or `/Users` (and so on down the line) or there may be a subtle issue where there are incorrect group permissions (and for example secondary groups are not being applied) or some fancy filesystem ACL involved. Again, these could be on any directory of the path.

```
% chmod 750 /Users/jhqdoe/perl5/lib/perl5
```

Okay let's break it another way. I'll break the MacPorts install this time as the Apple area might have security restrictions on it that prevent random changes (for better or worse).

```
% sudo chmod 000 "$(perl -Mstrict -E 'say $INC{"strict.pm"}')"
% perl -Mstrict -E 'say "borked?"'
Can't locate strict.pm:   /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.26/strict.pm: Permission denied.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

The solution is the same, look at all the directory paths in `@INC` and also the module name that `perl` is trying to load (here, `strict.pm`) and correct any permissions problems. There may be multiple errors. You may need to use a system tracing facility (`dtrace`, or `strace` on Linux) to help find what filesystem paths `perl` is looking at.

```
% sudo chmod 644 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.26/strict.pm
```

If `strict.pm` is instead not present, that's a different issue, and may indicate that critical files have been deleted or the installation was somehow botched or the hard drive is failing, or you're on a strange operating system (such as RedHat Linux) where `perl` has been chopped up into a variety of packages by the vendor.